# Duplicate images uploaded with Dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dragonfly-gem

I would like to copy a record that `has_many :pictures`. Copying the record is a no brainer, but copying the `Picture` records is something else.

- The `Picture` record has a link to a `Post`
- `Picture` has an attribute (for Dragonfly) that is `image_uid` that contains a string like `2016/08/17/3chjxpz97o_tfss_05bbc7ac_a432_4408_bf6e_a0fa3dc4630d_animage.jpeg`

The image is stored on an AWS S3 server. From the server perspective I think this does

- Download the image (original record `image_uid`) to the server
- Attach the image to the new `Picture` record
- Reupload the image to AWS
- Is there a method that just copies it on AWS, gives you the new `image_uid` so I can set it manually on the new record?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how this is done. For people who might ever need this:

My original `Picture` object:

```
#<Picture:0x007f82570f8f58> {
            :id => 285,
     :image_uid => "2016/10/06/6tacpx09uq_large_0.jpeg",
        :number => nil,
          :main => true,
    :created_at => Thu, 06 Oct 2016 08:59:44 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Thu, 06 Oct 2016 08:59:48 UTC +00:00,
       :user_id => 46,
    :company_id => 27,
        :public => true
}
```

Duplicating this is actually not that hard. I used the `.dup` method provided by Ruby. Copying multiple pictures:

```
pictures.each do |p|
  p2 = Picture.create(image:p.image, user:to_user, company:to_company, public:true, main: p.main)
end
```

The `image:p.image` is where you do the actual image duplication.